# Мне нужно сделать обработчик клика для елемента внутри iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно сделать обработчик клика для елемента внутри iframe.
Пробовал так, но ничего не работает

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'iframe .review-submit-button', function(e) {
 console.log('test');
});
```

Comment: а что выводит в e.target?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как можно это сделать:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});
```

Пример работы кода [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/).

> Примечание: это будет работать только в том случае, если обе страницы
>   находятся в одном домене.

Comment: iframe находится на другом домене, и так не работает

Comment: @james13 Тогда никак нельзя сделать это.